# Active Admin login not working (Devise + ActiveAdmin + Devise JWT)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, activeadmin

I'm using rails in API mode, with Devise and Devise JWT (for the API), and ActiveAdmin. I had everything working but I've been building out the API controllers and now ActiveAdmin auth is broken and I can't figure out what's going on.

So I tried to go to `/admin/login` directly and it works. I enter my username and password and when I click login, I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError in ActiveAdmin::Devise::SessionsController#create
private method `redirect_to' called for #<ActiveAdmin::Devise::SessionsController:0x0000000001d420>
```

I'm not quite sure why this would be broken since it's using mostly default settings.

My routes file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
  ...
```

I haven't changed anything in `ActiveAdmin::Devise` and I don't even have the files showing in my codebase.

In my Devise config:

```
config.authentication_method = :authenticate_admin_user!
config.current_user_method = :current_admin_user
```

and my non-activeadmin sessions controller looks like:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

module Users
  class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
    respond_to :json

    private

    def respond_with(resource, _opts = {})
      render json: {
        status: { code: 200, message: 'Logged in sucessfully.' },
        data: UserSerializer.new(resource).serializable_hash
      }, status: :ok
    end

    def respond_to_on_destroy
      if current_user
        render json: {
          status: 200,
          message: 'logged out successfully'
        }, status: :ok
      else
        render json: {
          status: 401,
          message: 'Couldn\'t find an active session.'
        }, status: :unauthorized
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And here's my admin user model:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class AdminUser < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
end
```

I don't believe the login is actually working when I just ignore the redirect error. I try to go to any of the pages and I get the same message `You need to sign in or sign up before continuing.`

Here is my application config:

```
    config.load_defaults 7.0
    config.api_only = true
    config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_interslice_session'

    # Required for all session management (regardless of session_store)
    config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Cookies
    config.middleware.use Rack::MethodOverride
    config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Flash
    config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore

    config.middleware.use config.session_store, config.session_options
```

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATED CODE:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  # https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.0.2.3/actionpack/lib/action_controller/api.rb#L104
  # skip modules that we need to load last
  ActionController::API.without_modules(:Instrumentation, :ParamsWrapper).each do |m|
    include m
  end

  # include what's missing
  include ActionController::ImplicitRender
  include ActionController::Helpers
  include ActionView::Layouts
  include ActionController::Flash
  include ActionController::MimeResponds

  # include modules that have to be last
  include ActionController::Instrumentation
  include ActionController::ParamsWrapper
  ActiveSupport.run_load_hooks(:action_controller_api, self)
  ActiveSupport.run_load_hooks(:action_controller, self)

  respond_to :json, :html

  def redirect_to(options = {}, response_options = {})
    super
  end
```

```
module Users
  class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
    respond_to :html
```

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)

  devise_for :users, defaults: { format: :json }, path: '', path_names: {
    sign_in: 'login',
    sign_out: 'logout',
    registration: 'signup'
  },
                     controllers: {
                       sessions: 'users/sessions',
                       registrations: 'users/registrations'
```

application config:

```
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Initialize configuration defaults for originally generated Rails version.
    config.load_defaults 7.0
    config.api_only = true
    config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_interslice_session'

    # Required for all session management (regardless of session_store)
    config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Cookies
    config.middleware.use Rack::MethodOverride
    config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Flash
    config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore
    config.middleware.use config.session_store, config.session_options
```

Comment: does it still happen if you remove `rememberable` from AdminUser ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the setup that I'm using, hopefully it's self-explanatory so we can get to the actual error.

```
# Gemfile
# ...
gem "sprockets-rails"
gem "sassc-rails"
gem 'activeadmin'
gem 'devise'
gem 'devise-jwt'
```

```
# config/application.rb
require_relative "boot"
require "rails/all"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_view/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)
module Rails7api
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.load_defaults 7.0
    config.api_only = true
    config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_interslice_session'
    config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Cookies
    config.middleware.use Rack::MethodOverride
    config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Flash
    config.middleware.use config.session_store, config.session_options
  end
end

# config/routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # Admin
  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)

  # Api (api_users, name is just for clarity)
  devise_for :api_users, defaults: { format: :json }
  namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
    resources :users
  end
end

# config/initializers/devise.rb
Devise.setup do |config|
  # ...
  config.jwt do |jwt|
    # jwt.secret = ENV['DEVISE_JWT_SECRET_KEY']
    jwt.secret = Rails.application.credentials.devise_jwt_secret_key!
  end
end
```

```
# db/migrate/20220424045738_create_authentication.rb
class CreateAuthentication < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    create_table :admin_users do |t|
      t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_index :admin_users, :email, unique: true

    create_table :api_users do |t|
      t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_index :api_users, :email, unique: true

    create_table :jwt_denylist do |t|
      t.string   :jti, null: false
      t.datetime :exp, null: false
    end
    add_index :jwt_denylist, :jti
  end
end
```

```
# app/models/admin_user.rb
class AdminUser < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable
end

# app/models/api_user.rb
class ApiUser < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :jwt_authenticatable, jwt_revocation_strategy: JwtDenylist
  self.skip_session_storage = [:http_auth, :params_auth] # https://github.com/waiting-for-dev/devise-jwt#session-storage-caveat
end

# app/models/jwt_denylist.rb
class JwtDenylist < ApplicationRecord
  include Devise::JWT::RevocationStrategies::Denylist
  self.table_name = 'jwt_denylist'
end
```

```
# app/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base      # for devise and active admin
  respond_to :json, :html
end

# app/api/application_controller.rb
module Api
  class ApplicationController < ActionController::API     # for api
    before_action :authenticate_api_user!
  end
end

# app/api/users_controller.rb
module Api
  class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def index
      render json: User.all
    end
  end
end
```

There are a few different ways people get this error, but they seem to be variations on the same issue. There is only one private `redirect_to` method I could find and it's even in the docs

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Flash.html#method-i-redirect_to

Both `active_admin` and `devise` inherit from `ApplicationController`

```
# ActiveAdmin::Devise::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController < DeviseController < Devise.parent_controller.constantize # <= @@parent_controller = "ApplicationController"

# ActiveAdmin::BaseController < ::InheritedResources::Base < ::ApplicationController
```

When `ApplicationController` inherits from `ActionController::API`, active admin breaks due to missing dependencies. So we have to include them one by one until rails boots and controller looks like this

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  include ActionController::Helpers       # FIXES undefined method `helper' for ActiveAdmin::Devise::SessionsController:Class (NoMethodError)
  include ActionView::Layouts             # FIXES undefined method `layout' for ActiveAdmin::Devise::SessionsController:Class (NoMethodError)
  include ActionController::Flash         # FIXES undefined method `flash' for #<ActiveAdmin::Devise::SessionsController:0x0000000000d840>):

  respond_to :json, :html                 # FIXES ActionController::UnknownFormat (ActionController::UnknownFormat):
end
```

This works until you try to log in and get `private method 'redirect_to'` error. A little bit of debugging and back-tracing points to `responders` gem,  it is responding with html, which is ok, even if our controller is api and calls redirect_to but hits `Flash#redirect_to` instead of `Redirecting#redirect_to`

```
  #0    ActionController::Flash#redirect_to(options="/admin", response_options_and_flash={}) at ~/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/flash.rb:52
  #1    ActionController::Responder#redirect_to at ~/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/responders-3.0.1/lib/action_controller/responder.rb:147
  #2    ActionController::Responder#navigation_behavior(error=#<ActionView::MissingTemplate: Missing t...) at ~/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/responders-3.0.1/lib/action_controller/responder.rb:207
  #3    ActionController::Responder#to_html at ~/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/responders-3.0.1/lib/action_controller/responder.rb:174
  #4    ActionController::Responder#to_html at ~/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/responders-3.0.1/lib/action_controller/responder.rb:171
  #5    ActionController::Responder#respond at ~/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/responders-3.0.1/lib/action_controller/responder.rb:165
  #6    ActionController::Responder.call(args=[#<ActiveAdmin::Devise::SessionsControll...) at ~/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/responders-3.0.1/lib/action_controller/responder.rb:158
  #7    ActionController::RespondWith#respond_with(resources=[#<AdminUser id: 1, email: "admin@user.c..., block=nil) at ~/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/responders-3.0.1/lib/action_controller/respond_with.rb:213
  #8    Devise::SessionsController#create at ~/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/devise-4.8.1/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb:23
```

Since `API` controller is quite a bit slimmer

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.0.2.3/actionpack/lib/action_controller/api.rb#L112

than `Base` controller

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.0.2.3/actionpack/lib/action_controller/base.rb#L205

it looks like something is missing. So a little bit of debugging and back-tracing with a `Base` controller does reveal an itsy bitsy difference.

```
  #0    ActionController::Flash#redirect_to(options="/admin", response_options_and_flash={}) at ~/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/flash.rb:52
  #1    block {|payload={:request=>#<ActionDispatch::Request POS...|} in redirect_to at ~/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:42
  #2    block in instrument at ~/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:206
  #3    ActiveSupport::Notifications::Instrumenter#instrument(name="redirect_to.action_controller", payload={:request=>#<ActionDispatch::Request POS...) at ~/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24
  #4    ActiveSupport::Notifications.instrument(name="redirect_to.action_controller", payload={:request=>#<ActionDispatch::Request POS...) at ~/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:206
  #5    ActionController::Instrumentation#redirect_to at ~/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41
  #6    ActionController::Responder#redirect_to at ~/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/responders-3.0.1/lib/action_controller/responder.rb:147
  #7    ActionController::Responder#navigation_behavior(error=#<ActionView::MissingTemplate: Missing t...) at ~/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/responders-3.0.1/lib/action_controller/responder.rb:207
  #8    ActionController::Responder#to_html at ~/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/responders-3.0.1/lib/action_controller/responder.rb:174
  #9    ActionController::Responder#to_html at ~/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/responders-3.0.1/lib/action_controller/responder.rb:171
  #10   ActionController::Responder#respond at ~/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/responders-3.0.1/lib/action_controller/responder.rb:165
  #11   ActionController::Responder.call(args=[#<ActiveAdmin::Devise::SessionsControll...) at ~/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/responders-3.0.1/lib/action_controller/responder.rb:158
  #12   ActionController::RespondWith#respond_with(resources=[#<AdminUser id: 1, email: "admin@user.c..., block=nil) at ~/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/responders-3.0.1/lib/action_controller/respond_with.rb:213
  #13   Devise::SessionsController#create at ~/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/devise-4.8.1/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb:23
```

I guess we were meant to hit `Instrumentation#redirect_to` first. It is noted that the `Instrumentation` needs to be loaded later than other modules. In the `Base` controller `Flash` module comes before `Instrumentation`. But we included `Flash` last and messed things up. I don't know if there is a better way of changing the order of these modules:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Metal
  # https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.0.2.3/actionpack/lib/action_controller/api.rb#L104
  # skip modules that we need to load last
  ActionController::API.without_modules(:Instrumentation, :ParamsWrapper).each do |m|
    include m
  end

  # include what's missing
  include ActionController::ImplicitRender
  include ActionController::Helpers
  include ActionView::Layouts
  include ActionController::Flash
  include ActionController::MimeResponds

  # include modules that have to be last
  include ActionController::Instrumentation
  include ActionController::ParamsWrapper
  ActiveSupport.run_load_hooks(:action_controller_api, self)
  ActiveSupport.run_load_hooks(:action_controller, self)

  respond_to :json, :html
end
```

It fixes the error. But I feel like `ApplicationController` should inherit from `Base`, it makes things much simpler, because it is used by devise and active admin, using `API` and adding modules back for active admin seems like running in circles.

@brcebn workaround does work. Just get in that private method like all the cool kids do. https://github.com/heartcombo/responders/issues/222#issue-661963658

```
def redirect_to(options = {}, response_options = {})
  super
end
```

Also this got a little hairy, so I had to write some tests. These only work when `ApplicationController` inherits from `Base`.

```
# spec/requests/authentication_spec.rb
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe 'Authentication', type: :request do
  describe 'Edge case for Devise + JWT + RailsAPI + ActiveAdmin configuration' do
    # This set up will raise private method error
    #
    #   class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
    #     include ActionController::Helpers
    #     include ActionView::Layouts
    #     include ActionController::Flash    # <= has private.respond_to
    #
    #     respond_to :json, :html # when responding with html in an api controller
    #   end
    #
    before { AdminUser.create!(params) }
    let(:params) { { email: 'admin@user.com', password: '123456' } }

    it do
      RSpec::Expectations.configuration.on_potential_false_positives = :nothing
      expect{
        post(admin_user_session_path, params: { admin_user: params })
      }.to_not raise_error(NoMethodError)
    end

    it do
      expect{
        post(admin_user_session_path, params: { admin_user: params })
      }.to_not raise_error
    end
  end

  describe 'POST /api/users/sign_in' do
    before { ApiUser.create!(params) }
    before { post api_user_session_path, params: { api_user: params } }

    let(:params) { { email: 'api@user.com', password: '123456' } }

    it { expect(response).to have_http_status(:created) }
    it { expect(headers['Authorization']).to include 'Bearer' }
    it 'should not have admin access' do
      get admin_dashboard_path
      expect(response).to have_http_status(:redirect)
      follow_redirect!
      expect(request.path).to eq '/admin/login'
    end
  end

  describe 'GET /api/users' do
    context 'when signed out' do
      before { get api_users_path }

      it { expect(response.body).to include 'You need to sign in or sign up before continuing.' }
    end

    context 'when signed in' do
      before { ApiUser.create!(params) }
      before { post api_user_session_path, params: { api_user: params } }

      let(:params) { { email: 'api@user.com', password: '123456' } }

      it 'should not authorize without Authorization header' do
        get api_users_path
        expect(response.body).to include 'You need to sign in or sign up before continuing.'
      end

      it 'should authorize with Authorization header' do
        get api_users_path, headers: { 'Authorization': headers['Authorization'] }
        expect(response.body).to_not include 'You need to sign in or sign up before continuing.'
      end
    end
  end

  describe 'GET /admin' do
    it do
      get admin_root_path
      expect(response).to have_http_status(:redirect)
    end

    context 'when api_user is authorized' do
      before { ApiUser.create!(params) }
      before { post api_user_session_path, params: { api_user: params } }

      let(:params) { { email: 'api@user.com', password: '123456' } }

      it 'should redirect without raising' do
        get admin_root_path
        expect(response).to have_http_status(:redirect)
      end
    end
  end

  describe 'POST /admin/login' do
    before { AdminUser.create!(params) }
    before { post admin_user_session_path, params: { admin_user: params } }

    let(:params) { { email: 'admin@user.com', password: '123456' } }

    it do
      expect(response).to have_http_status(:redirect)
      follow_redirect!
      expect(response.body).to include 'Signed in successfully.'
    end
  end

  describe 'DELETE /admin/logout' do
    before { AdminUser.create!(params) }
    before { post admin_user_session_path, params: { admin_user: params } }

    let(:params) { { email: 'admin@user.com', password: '123456' } }

    it 'should sign out' do
      delete destroy_admin_user_session_path
      expect(response).to have_http_status(:redirect)
      follow_redirect!
      expect(request.path).to eq '/unauthenticated' # <= what?
      follow_redirect!
      expect(response.body).to include 'Signed out successfully.'
      expect(request.path).to eq '/admin/login'
    end
  end
end
```

```
$ rspec spec/requests/authentication_spec.rb
...........

Finished in 0.48745 seconds (files took 0.83 seconds to load)
11 examples, 0 failures
```

**Update**

The above solution with `ActionController::API.without_modules` seems to be super buggy or not the correct way to do that or `ActiveSupport` hooks were not meant to be run inside `ApplicationController`.

The only other way I've found is to define full custom controller and inherit from it. The inheritance part seems to be important (drop a comment if you know why).

```
# app/controllers/base_controller.rb

class BaseController < ActionController::Metal
  abstract!

  # Order of modules is important
  # See: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.0.2.3/actionpack/lib/action_controller/base.rb#L205
  MODULES = [
    AbstractController::Rendering,

    # Extra modules #################

    ActionController::Helpers,
    ActionView::Layouts,
    ActionController::MimeResponds,
    ActionController::Flash,
    
    #################################

    ActionController::UrlFor,
    ActionController::Redirecting,
    ActionController::ApiRendering,
    ActionController::Renderers::All,
    ActionController::ConditionalGet,
    ActionController::BasicImplicitRender,
    ActionController::StrongParameters,

    ActionController::DataStreaming,
    ActionController::DefaultHeaders,
    ActionController::Logging,

    # Before callbacks should also be executed as early as possible, so
    # also include them at the bottom.
    AbstractController::Callbacks,

    # Append rescue at the bottom to wrap as much as possible.
    ActionController::Rescue,

    # Add instrumentations hooks at the bottom, to ensure they instrument
    # all the methods properly.
    ActionController::Instrumentation,

    # Params wrapper should come before instrumentation so they are
    # properly showed in logs
    ActionController::ParamsWrapper
  ]

  MODULES.each do |mod|
    include mod
  end

  ActiveSupport.run_load_hooks(:action_controller_api, self)
  ActiveSupport.run_load_hooks(:action_controller, self)
end
```

```
# app/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < BaseController   # use for everything
  respond_to :json, :html
end

# app/api/users_controller.rb
module Api
  class UsersController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_api_user!
    def index
      render json: User.all
    end
  end
end
```

Tested!

```
12 examples, 0 failures
```

Comment: Thank you for the thorough response. I tried adding redirect_to as a public method to `SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController` but it didn't work. Feels like it would need to go on the active admin sessions controller, which isn't mounted in my codebase. 

Do I need to do that in combination with other things you suggested? Do I still need to load the modules in a different order?

Comment: I tried adding everything you mentioned, maybe I didn't do it correctly? I'm going to update my original question with my updated code.

Comment: I also tried defining `redirect_to` publicly in application controller, still nothing

Comment: notice the `ActionController::Metal`. make sure to restart the server. is `Users::Sessions` hooked up in the `devise_for` in the routes?

Comment: make sure you don't have same `includes` twice in `ApplicationController` and in `SessionsController`

Comment: What is the `Metal` part? I have been restarting the server :)

```
  devise_for :users, defaults: { format: :json }, path: '', path_names: {
    sign_in: 'login',
    sign_out: 'logout',
    registration: 'signup'
  },
                     controllers: {
                       sessions: 'users/sessions',
                       registrations: 'users/registrations'
                     }
```

here's my route for users

Comment: Oh wow i just deleted the includes from sessions controller and that fixed it!

Comment: I feel like i have a lot of duplicate or unneeded code now...i'm going to edit the original post again to include all files if you wouldn't mind reviewing

Comment: Also, as a last piece of this puzzle, logging out of admin does not redirect anywhere. and going to /admin when not logged in displays "You need to sign in or sign up before continuing." rather than redirecting to /admin/login. any ideas how to get those working?

Comment: And to confirm, do i need to both change the loading order of modules AND define redirect_to publicly?

Comment: `Metal` is the very base rails controller, `API < Metal`. because we need redefine the whole module stack we can't inherit from `API`. '/admin' should be picked up by active admin, probably `before_action :authenticate_user!` gets in the way. I had to have a separeate api controller to fix that. you don't need to define `redirect_to`

Comment: Interestingly enough, only redefining `redirect_to` alone makes everything work. is there a benefit to changing the other things you mentioned?

Comment: redefining `redirect_to` only skips `ActionController::Instrumentation`, I guess you'll be missing a few lines of logs (maybe more than a few).

Comment: Both ways work! Thank you so much.

Comment: Actually, other things started breaking by switching the module load order, such as: undefined method `'paginate' for #<API::V1::CustomersController:0x0000000001e758>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244167/discussion-between-matthew-berman-and-alex).

Answer (score 0):

Based on your error message. It seems to be root is not set for active_admin.

After signing in a user, confirming the account or updating the password, Devise will look for a scoped root path to redirect to. For instance, when using a `:user` resource, the `user_root_path` will be used if it exists; otherwise, the default `root_path` will be used. This means that you need to set the root inside your routes:

```
root to: 'home#index'
```

You can also override `after_sign_in_path_for` and `after_sign_out_path_for` to customize your redirect hooks.

Took a reference from [here](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/heartcombo/devise).

Comment: I'm not sure that is the issue as it doesn't have to do with the private method issue I described: `NoMethodError in ActiveAdmin::Devise::SessionsController#create
private method `redirect_to' called for`

Comment: Did you try already? Also, I found this https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/6442

Comment: Yes this looks related and no it didn’t fix the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. In my case, it was linked to the gem `responders`. Here is my [issue](https://github.com/heartcombo/responders/issues/222) about it, still unsolved.